# Regex Python / group quantifiers

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, quantifiers

I want to match a list of variables which look like directories, e.g.:

```
Same/Same2/Foot/Ankle/Joint/Actuator/Sensor/Temperature/Value=4.123
Same/Same2/Battery/Name=SomeString
Same/Same2/Home/Land/Some/More/Stuff=0.34
```

The length of the "subdirectories" is variable having an upper bound (above it's 9). 
I want to group every subdirectory except the 1st one which I named "Same" above.

The best I could come up with is:

```
^(?:([^/]+)/){4,8}([^/]+)=(.*)
```

It already looks for 4-8 subdirectories but only groups the last one. Why's that?
Is there a better solution using group quantifiers?

Edit: Solved. Will use split() instead.

Comment: Is regex really necessary for you?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `split` and other regular Python string management functions instead of using regular expressions?

Comment: The list contains thousands of these directories which are to be parsed into variable names after a specific convention, e.g. Same/Same2/Battery/Name=SomeString becoming SAME2_BATTERY_NAME=SomeString. Is there a better way than regex?

Comment: Hm. Thanks, never thought of split. Makes it a lot easier and faster! :)

Comment: btw, your solution doesn't work because with repeating group patterns, only the last match is returned

Comment: so, just our of curiosity - there's no (whatsoever obvious) solution using python regex?

Comment: @malch Yes there is, see my solution. But I wonder what advantage we gain to use a regex instead of split() as Andrew White does. Maybe the fact that it can be more easily adapted to either Windows or Linux platform by using os.sep

Comment: @malch, I removed the "(SOLVED)" from the title of your question. Please accept the answer that resolved the issue for you by clicking the "V"-like shaped icon next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

regx = re.compile('(?:(?<=\A)|(?<=/)).+?(?=/|\Z)')


for ss in ('Same/Same2/Foot/Ankle/Joint/Actuator/Sensor/Temperature/Value=4.123',
           'Same/Same2/Battery/Name=SomeString',
           'Same/Same2/Home/Land/Some/More/Stuff=0.34'):

    print ss
    print regx.findall(ss)
    print
```

### Edit 1

Now you have given more info on what you want to obtain ( _"Same/Same2/Battery/Name=SomeString becoming SAME2_BATTERY_NAME=SomeString"_ ) better solutions can be proposed: either with a regex or with split() , + replace()

```
import re
from os import sep

sep2 = r'\\' if sep=='\\' else '/'

pat = '^(?:.+?%s)(.+$)' % sep2
print 'pat==%s\n' % pat

ragx = re.compile(pat)

for ss in ('Same\Same2\Foot\Ankle\Joint\Actuator\Sensor\Temperature\Value=4.123',
           'Same\Same2\Battery\Name=SomeString',
           'Same\Same2\Home\Land\Some\More\Stuff=0.34'):

    print ss
    print ragx.match(ss).group(1).replace(sep,'_')
    print ss.split(sep,1)[1].replace(sep,'_')
    print
```

result

```
pat==^(?:.+?\\)(.+$)

Same\Same2\Foot\Ankle\Joint\Actuator\Sensor\Temperature\Value=4.123
Same2_Foot_Ankle_Joint_Actuator_Sensor_Temperature_Value=4.123
Same2_Foot_Ankle_Joint_Actuator_Sensor_Temperature_Value=4.123

Same\Same2\Battery\Name=SomeString
Same2_Battery_Name=SomeString
Same2_Battery_Name=SomeString

Same\Same2\Home\Land\Some\More\Stuff=0.34
Same2_Home_Land_Some_More_Stuff=0.34
Same2_Home_Land_Some_More_Stuff=0.34
```

### Edit 2

Re-reading your comment, I realized that I didn't take in account that you want to upper the part of the strings that lies before the '=' sign but not after it.

Hence, this new code that exposes 3 methods that answer this requirement. You will choose which one you prefer:

```
import re

from os import sep
sep2 = r'\\' if sep=='\\' else '/'



pot = '^(?:.+?%s)(.+?)=([^=]*$)' % sep2
print 'pot==%s\n' % pot
rogx = re.compile(pot)

pet = '^(?:.+?%s)(.+?(?==[^=]*$))' % sep2
print 'pet==%s\n' % pet
regx = re.compile(pet)


for ss in ('Same\Same2\Foot\Ankle\Joint\Sensor\Value=4.123',
           'Same\Same2\Battery\Name=SomeString',
           'Same\Same2\Ocean\Atlantic\North=',
           'Same\Same2\Maths\Addition\\2+2=4\Simple=ohoh'):
    print ss + '\n' + len(ss)*'-'

    print 'rogx groups  '.rjust(32),rogx.match(ss).groups()

    a,b = ss.split(sep,1)[1].rsplit('=',1)
    print 'split split  '.rjust(32),(a,b)
    print 'split split join upper replace   %s=%s' % (a.replace(sep,'_').upper(),b)

    print 'regx split group  '.rjust(32),regx.match(ss.split(sep,1)[1]).group()
    print 'regx split sub  '.rjust(32),\
          regx.sub(lambda x: x.group(1).replace(sep,'_').upper(), ss)
    print
```

result, on a Windows platform

```
pot==^(?:.+?\\)(.+?)=([^=]*$)

pet==^(?:.+?\\)(.+?(?==[^=]*$))

Same\Same2\Foot\Ankle\Joint\Sensor\Value=4.123
----------------------------------------------
                   rogx groups   ('Same2\\Foot\\Ankle\\Joint\\Sensor\\Value', '4.123')
                   split split   ('Same2\\Foot\\Ankle\\Joint\\Sensor\\Value', '4.123')
split split join upper replace   SAME2_FOOT_ANKLE_JOINT_SENSOR_VALUE=4.123
              regx split group   Same2\Foot\Ankle\Joint\Sensor\Value
                regx split sub   SAME2_FOOT_ANKLE_JOINT_SENSOR_VALUE=4.123

Same\Same2\Battery\Name=SomeString
----------------------------------
                   rogx groups   ('Same2\\Battery\\Name', 'SomeString')
                   split split   ('Same2\\Battery\\Name', 'SomeString')
split split join upper replace   SAME2_BATTERY_NAME=SomeString
              regx split group   Same2\Battery\Name
                regx split sub   SAME2_BATTERY_NAME=SomeString

Same\Same2\Ocean\Atlantic\North=
--------------------------------
                   rogx groups   ('Same2\\Ocean\\Atlantic\\North', '')
                   split split   ('Same2\\Ocean\\Atlantic\\North', '')
split split join upper replace   SAME2_OCEAN_ATLANTIC_NORTH=
              regx split group   Same2\Ocean\Atlantic\North
                regx split sub   SAME2_OCEAN_ATLANTIC_NORTH=

Same\Same2\Maths\Addition\2+2=4\Simple=ohoh
-------------------------------------------
                   rogx groups   ('Same2\\Maths\\Addition\\2+2=4\\Simple', 'ohoh')
                   split split   ('Same2\\Maths\\Addition\\2+2=4\\Simple', 'ohoh')
split split join upper replace   SAME2_MATHS_ADDITION_2+2=4_SIMPLE=ohoh
              regx split group   Same2\Maths\Addition\2+2=4\Simple
                regx split sub   SAME2_MATHS_ADDITION_2+2=4_SIMPLE=ohoh
```

Comment: Awesome. Thx for offering a solution which shows both approaches so elegantly!

Answer (score 2):

I probably misunderstood what exactly you want to do, but here is how you would do it without regex:

```
for entry in list_of_vars:
    key, value = entry.split('=')
    key_components = key.split('/')
    if 4 <= len(key_components) <= 8:
        # here the actual work is done
        print "%s=%s" % ('_'.join(key_components[1:]).upper(), value)
```

Comment: @hop I don't see the interest to split according to '=' to obtain the key value that is then splitted. Function split() has a default argument that can be set to 1 to split only on the first '/'

Answer (score 1):

Just use split?

```
>>> p='Same/Same2/Foot/Ankle/Joint/Actuator/Sensor/Temperature/Value=4.123'
>>> p.split('/')
['Same', 'Same2', 'Foot', 'Ankle', 'Joint', 'Actuator', 'Sensor', 'Temperature', 'Value=4.123']
```

Also, if you want that key/val pair you can do something like this...

```
>>> s = p.split('/')
>>> s[-1].split('=')
['Value', '4.123']
```

Comment: I agree with this approach. The final list of variables should however be `p.split('/')[1:]`, as to leave out the initial `Same` value.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of variations on your theme.  For one, I've always found regexen to be cryptic to the point of unmaintainable, so I wrote the pyparsing module.  In my mind, I look at your code and think, "oh, it's a list of '/'-delimited strings, an '=' sign, and then some kind of rvalue."  And that translates pretty directly into the pyparsing parser definition code.  By adding a name here and there in the parser ("key" and "value", similar to named groups in regex), the output is pretty easily processed.

```
data="""\
Same/Same2/Foot/Ankle/Joint/Actuator/Sensor/Temperature/Value=4.123
Same/Same2/Battery/Name=SomeString
Same/Same2/Home/Land/Some/More/Stuff=0.34""".splitlines()

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphanums, Word, nums, QuotedString, delimitedList

wd = Word(alphas, alphanums)
number = Word(nums+'+-', nums+'.').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
rvalue = wd | number | QuotedString('"')

defn = delimitedList(wd, '/')('key') + '=' + rvalue('value')

for d in data:
    result = defn.parseString(d)
```

Second, I question your approach at defining all of those variable names - creating variable names on the fly based on your data is a pretty well-recognized Code Smell (not necessarily bad, but you might *really* want to rethink this approach).  I used a recursive defaultdict to create a navigable structure so that you can easily do operations like "find all the entries that are sub-elements of "Same2" (in this case, "Foot", "Battery", and "Home") - this kind of work is more difficult when trying to sift through some collection of variable names as found in locals(), it seems to me you will end up re-parsing these names to reconstruct the key hierarchy.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class recursivedefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, attrFactory=int):
        self.default_factory = lambda : type(self)(attrFactory)
        self._attrFactory = attrFactory
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        newval = self._attrFactory()
        setattr(self, attr, newval)
        return newval

table = recursivedefaultdict()

# parse each entry, and accumulate into hierarchical dict
for d in data:
    # use pyparsing parser, gives us key (list of names) and value
    result = defn.parseString(d)
    t = table
    for k in result.key[:-1]:
        t = t[k]
    t[result.key[-1]] = result.value


# recursive method to iterate over hierarchical dict    
def showTable(t, indent=''):
    for k,v in t.items():
        print indent+k,
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            print
            showTable(v, indent+'  ')
        else:
            print v

showTable(table)
```

Prints:

```
Same
  Same2
    Foot
      Ankle
        Joint
          Actuator
            Sensor
              Temperature
                Value 4.123
    Battery
      Name SomeString
    Home
      Land
        Some
          More
            Stuff 0.34
```

If you are **really** set on defining those variable names, then adding some helpful parse actions to pyparsing will reformat the parsed data at parse time, so that it's directly processable afterwards:

```
wd = Word(alphas, alphanums)
number = Word(nums+'+-', nums+'.').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
rvaluewd = wd.copy().setParseAction(lambda t: '"%s"' % t[0])
rvalue = rvaluewd | number | QuotedString('"')

defn = delimitedList(wd, '/')('key') + '=' + rvalue('value')

def joinNamesWithAllCaps(tokens):
    tokens["key"] = '_'.join(map(str.upper, tokens.key))
defn.setParseAction(joinNamesWithAllCaps)

for d in data:
    result = defn.parseString(d)
    print result.key,'=', result.value
```

Prints:

```
SAME_SAME2_FOOT_ANKLE_JOINT_ACTUATOR_SENSOR_TEMPERATURE_VALUE = 4.123
SAME_SAME2_BATTERY_NAME = "SomeString"
SAME_SAME2_HOME_LAND_SOME_MORE_STUFF = 0.34
```

(Note that this also encloses your SomeString value in quotes, so that the resulting assignment statement is valid Python.)